# Releasing all schema locks in ArcGIS GDB

Tags: arcgis-server, arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase

We use ArcGIS 10.3 products (Server, Desktop) with Oracle database. Our problem is we can not make any schema changes because of shared schema locks unless we stop all services and kill all database connections. Even though we disable "Lock database schema" option for services, there are still some locks we can not figure out which user or service it belongs to. With ArcObjects we get a list ISchemaLockInfo but it only contains tablename, username and locktype properties.

When we investigate SDE schema, there is a table "TABLE_LOCKS". Is deleting all rows in this table or disconnecting all users from database (kill connections) bad idea? Or is there any other any way (manually or programmatically) for getting an exlusive lock?

Comment: "unless we stop all services and kill all database connections" - this has always been required, in my experience, to change a schema.